# rails generate active_admin:install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

I run rails g active-admin:install

with Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'devise',      '> 4.x'
gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 3.5.0.beta1'
gem 'ransack',    github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
gem 'kaminari',   github: 'amatsuda/kaminari', branch: '0-17-stable'
gem 'formtastic', github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
gem 'draper',     github: 'audionerd/draper', branch: 'rails5', ref: 'e816e0e587'
gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml', github: 'rails/activemodel-serializers-xml'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler',          github: 'MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler'
gem 'database_cleaner',            github: 'pschambacher/database_cleaner', branch: 'rails5.0', ref: '430a957'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
```

But get error:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:74:in `insert': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:74:in `insert'
```

When I run:

```
bundle install
```

It works perfectly.

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

Solved by install or update ruby version.

Comment: Same issue occured, I do the changes and rub as answer below

Answer (score 2):

Please do update the Gemfile as:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
```

and run

`rails g active_admin:install`

Comment: Still I have error

`/home/user.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:74:in insert': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)`

Do you know why?

Comment: It is bug in the previous version due to compatibility issue. Could you please update rails to latest code as on GitHub.

Comment: so, I change gem `'rails', '~> 5.0.0'`?